# How do I patch a specific subdocument in an array

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

I have at collection of documents with this structure

```
{"_id":"mrc",
  "Name":"MRC Odense",
  "events":[
  {"date":"01/12/2020","title":"Løb","uuid":"4ee494ac-e73c-4945-ac19-25c9d6882707"},
  {,"date":"01/12/2020","title":"Løb","uuid":"925a99d3-8d77-425a-ad54-a893d5c14d72"}
  ]
}
```

I get at patch request with the uuid of an event. How can I update the specific event?

```
def patch(self,event_uuid=None):
    r = request.get_json(force=True)   # r={"title"="new title"}
    doc=self.col.find_one({"events.uuid":id})
    ....??
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in r:
  self.col.update_one({"events.uuid":id }, {'$set' : {  "events.$."+key : r[key]}} )
```